# How to count unique value in a table with other condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have this (sample) source of data where I want to count the number of unique Client/ID in total and from a specif location.

I am good at counting the number of unique clients in total using MS Excel solutions, at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273.

[image: See screenshoot]

However, I can't figure out how to count the unique Client/ID from the location of "Cabaret".

I have tried using `=SUMPRODUCT()` but it is not working.

[image: See screenshoot]

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(AllSales[[ID]:[ID]],AllSales[[ID]:[ID]],0),   MATCH(AllSales[[ID]:[ID]],AllSales[[ID]:[ID]], 0))>0, 1, 0), IF(AllSales[Location]="Cabaret", 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second criteria needs to be multiplied against the first inside the Frequency:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(AllSales[[ID]:[ID]],AllSales[[ID]:[ID]],0)*(AllSales[Location]="Cabaret"), MATCH(AllSales[[ID]:[ID]],AllSales[[ID]:[ID]], 0))>0))
```

[image]